# Fomento de clics accidentales: diseño (Infracción políticas de Admob )

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, admob

Buenos días hoy he recibido un nuevo aviso por parte de Admob diciendo el siguiente mensaje:

**Fomento de clics accidentales: diseño**

Advertencia: Corríjalo antes del 20 sept

Alguien con el mismo problema? Siempre he utilizado este mismo diseño y nunca he tenido problemas.

Creo que uno de los posibles errores seria no dejar un espacio o borde entre un scrollview y el LinearLayout del banner de Admob.

Ejemplo de mi codigo xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
      android:background="@drawable/fondo">
      
            <LinearLayout  android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center" android:layout_marginTop="5dp">
            
                <TextView style="@style/titles" 
                android:id="@+id/textView1" 
                android:text="@string/title1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_gravity="center" 
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp" 
                android:layout_marginRight="30dp" 
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"> 
                </TextView>
                <Button
                    style="@style/textobtns" 
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"   
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"  
                android:text="@string/regresar" 
                android:id="@+id/btback"
                android:background="@drawable/android_back" 
                android:onClick="Back"> 
                </Button>
            </LinearLayout>
    
    
        <ScrollView android:id="@+id/scrollView1" 
         android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
         android:layout_marginTop="15dp" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="3"
            style="@style/fondo">
    
                 <TextView style="@style/info" 
                android:text="@string/text_info1"
                android:id="@+id/textView2" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_gravity="top|center" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:paddingLeft="5dp" android:paddingRight="5dp">
                </TextView>
               
                
                 
       </ScrollView>
    
        
    
        <LinearLayout  android:gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/ad_main"/>
    
</LinearLayout>
```

Información Google Admob:

Implementaciones de banner recomendadas
https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6275335
Apartado: Anuncio separado del contenido de la aplicación por un borde

Antes del LinearLayout del banner que pondríais?

```
</ScrollView>

**(espacio/borde)**

<LinearLayout  android:gravity="bottom"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/ad_main"/>
```

Gracias por los comentarios ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Lo que se debe tratar de evitar es que mientras se genera la carga de un anuncio, al tratar el usuario de realizar otra accion el anuncio una vez cargado se active accidentalmente.

Por ejemplo trata de cargar el anuncio en otra pantalla y no en la que el usuario puede realizar clics para cargar otra pantalla.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

incluso otra opcion es realizar la carga del anuncio cuando se llama el metodo `onBackPressed()` , revisa

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40858027/show-interstitial-ad-on-back-button-pressed

```
InterstitialAd interstitialAd = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_blue);

   interstitialAd= new InterstitialAd(this);
    interstitialAd.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.interstitial_full_screen));
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    interstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);

}


@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
if (interstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
    interstitialAd.show();
    interstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {
            super.onAdClosed();
            finish();
        }
    });
   }else{
       super.onBackPressed();
   }

}
```

Comment: Hola, los anuncios intersticiales creo que los utilizo correcatmente al realizar clic en un botón de la pagina principal se visualiza el intersticial y despues el activity.
Ejemplo pagina_principal -> intersticial -> pagina2

Answer (score 0):

Estoy pensando que podría ser fallo por una posible mala implementación de los anuncios intersticiales al momento de mostrarlos.

Ejemplo código que utilizo en el button del menú general para acceder en la pagina 2:

```
public void btn1(View view)
{
    Random randQuery = new Random();
    int numRandom = randQuery.nextInt(10);

    Intent i= new Intent(this,p2.class);
    startActivity(i);

    
    if (numRandom<=1 && interstitial!=null && interstitial.isLoaded())
    {
        interstitial.show();
    }
    
}
```

- El random es para que los anuncios no se activen tantas veces.
- En todas las pruebas que realizo el intersticial se visualiza antes de la pagina 2.